# AQGridView ensuring only visible cell is loaded

Tags: cell, visible, aqgridview

I am using AQGridView to load images in a horiztonal layout (landscape). I've noticed that the grid actually loads 2 cells (where only 1 is actually visible),a nice solution but for this project I need to be able to ensure that strictly ONLY the visible cell is loaded and not the next non-visible cell in addition. I'm quite sure I will have to hack this in, any pointers on where in the AQGridView or supporting code I would have to do this?? Hope my question is clear and thanks in advance for any help!